# Inkscape - Get interpolation parameters

Tags: inkscape

After using Inkscape's [interpolation](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/interpolate/tutorial-interpolate.en.html), is there a straight-forward way of getting the parameters that were used to create the result?

Interpolation dialog with sample params:

[image: Sample interpolation params dialog]

---

#### Motivation:

I'm experimenting with different interpolation params, to see which yield best looking result. Labelling different outputs with text tool is my current approach, but perhaps there is a better way.

As mentioned, I'm looking for a straight-forward solution. For instance, measuring distance between interpolation steps to learn the exponent, is a total overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *straight-forward* way to retrieve the interpolation parameters. To be precise: There is *no way at all* to retrieve the *exact* parameters.
Interpolation is not an effect, but generates new obejcts. The new objects are just like any other object. The SVG does not contain any hints that they were generated.

**Suggestions:**

- Use *live preview* to play around.
- Modify the "interpolate" extension to add a text with the parameters used. Location of the script is listed under `Edit > Preferences > System`, `System Data`. The script file is named `interp.py`.
- Write a script that generates a table of labeled interpolation examples for lots of different parameter combinations.

This answer is not satisfying, but that's the way it is. Sorry.

Comment: That's what I feared - objects generated by interpolation might not contain any additional metadata. Have you seen any confirmation of this in some docs form?

Comment: No. I haven't read the documentation to answer this question. I read the svg file (as text) and looked at the source code of the interpolation script.

Comment: And that's is even better than looking that up in the docs :)
(The interpolation docs being only the tutorial I linked in the question)